# Wordpress Demo Pages for Tutorials

Tags: php, wordpress, demo

I have a few tutorials that I would like to write up. Many web-based tutorials have a demo page and a zip download of the demo. I can easily upload a zip file to my post, but the for the demo i'm not quite sure. The demo page would need to be different from the theme I'm currently using. One example of this style would be http://css-tricks.com/3d-text-tower/ . Does anyone know how to make a demo page in this style using wordpress?

Comment: How did you solve it? Me and maybe others would like to know.

Comment: i believe i uploaded an html document using the upload tool and then just linked directly to that from my app, unfortunately I took my site down, so ... i'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you linked, I think the demo is (probably) just a static page in an "examples" subfolder of the site.  So that wouldn't be a good example of what you want, since it's not tied in to WordPress or whatever CMS they're using.

If you need a demo to live within a specific design, just create a new [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) which strips out unneeded stuff or otherwise gives you a nice canvas area for the demo.  Once you have that, you can make a new page for the demo, select the demo template, and paste the code into the HTML tab of the WordPress editor.

Comment: It turns out that you can upload html pages using the upload tool, though all js/css has to be one one page, i looked into templates, but if you put css in them, it gets scrubbed and i'm not sure how to get around that.

Comment: Huh, I'm not sure what's going wrong for you there.  Are you putting your code in the HTML (not "Visual") input field of the page post?  I tried it on my site and inline <style> and <script> statements will work even if outside of the <head> element.  Not sure what could be "scrubbing" your CSS.